# Retrieve JDO object without certain attribute

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, jdo

I have a class `Post` and within it I have a `list` of `Reviews`. Is it possible to retrieve a `Post` object without `reviewList` (or as an empty list)? Or maybe I should use some other model to achieve this.

```
@PersistenceCapable
class Post {
   @PrimaryKey
   @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
   long id;

   @Persistent
   String title;

   @Persistent
   List<Review> reviewList;
}
```

.

```
@PersistenceCapable
class Review {
   @PrimaryKey
   @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
   long id;

   @Persistent
   String comment;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The documentation](http://code.google.com/intl/en/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jdo/relationships.html#Owned_One_to_Many_Relationships) says:

> Accessing a collection performs a query

I read this as: *the collection is lazy-loaded*. This means that when you load a Post, its reviews are not laoded. They will be loaded automatically when you access the collection (i.e. when calling any method of the collection).

Comment: Doesn't this simply mean that the query will be performed when the parent object is loaded?

Comment: No. The sentence says: "Accessing a collection". It doesn't say "loading an object containing a collection". This is a typical way of handling relationships in ORMs. It it didn't do that, loading A would load its Bs, which would load its Cs, which would load its Ds, etc.